# How to get client's Wi-Fi coordinates using JavaScript or nodejs or Java

Tags: javascript, java, node-modules, latitude-longitude, google-geolocation

Please guys help me, I had spent lot of time but unable to figure out the solution.

I want to get Wi-Fi coordinates(mac-address, signal strength, signal-to-noise ratio, channel, etc.) of the client, which I will send to
**https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=YOUR_API_KEY**
to get latitude and longitude.

I tried following things:

-HTML5 geolocation API, but it is not giving exact location and accuracy is not good.

-Nodejs libraries(node-wifi, node-wifi-scanner, etc), but it is giving Wi-Fi coordinates of the server's machine not of client's machine.

-JAVA is also giving server's Wi-Fi information.

Angular is also not providing Wi-Fi coordinates.

I use this Nodejs code

```
 const wifi = require('node-wifi');
  wifi.init({
    iface: null // network interface, choose a random wifi interface if set to null
  });

  // Scan networks
wifi.scan((error:any, networks:any) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {

    console.log(networks);

  }
});
```

I got this result:

```
[
  {
    mac: '60:a4:b7:56:e5:45',
    bssid: '60:a4:b7:56:e5:45',
    ssid: 'FGRF Wifi',
    channel: 9,
    frequency: 2452,
    signal_level: -65.5,
    quality: 69,
    security: 'WPA2-Personal',
    security_flags: 'CCMP ',
    mode: 'Unknown'
  },
  {
    mac: '62:a4:b7:66:e5:45',
    bssid: '62:a4:b7:66:e5:45',
    ssid: '',
    channel: 9,
    frequency: 2452,
    signal_level: -65.5,
    quality: 69,
    security: 'WPA2-Personal',
    security_flags: 'CCMP ',
    mode: 'Unknown'
  },
  {
    mac: '58:c1:7a:c6:b6:80',
    bssid: '58:c1:7a:c6:b6:80',
    ssid: 'FGRF',
    channel: 11,
    frequency: 2462,
    signal_level: -65.5,
    quality: 69,
    security: 'WPA2-Personal',
    security_flags: 'CCMP ',
    mode: 'Unknown'
  },
  {
    mac: 'e4:83:26:cb:28:58',
    bssid: 'e4:83:26:cb:28:58',
    ssid: 'HUAWEI-23p7',
    channel: 6,
    frequency: 2437,
    signal_level: -63.5,
    quality: 73,
    security: 'WPA2-Personal',
    security_flags: 'CCMP ',
    mode: 'Unknown'
  },
  {
    mac: 'f4:a4:d6:4c:fd:90',
    bssid: 'f4:a4:d6:4c:fd:90',
    ssid: 'FGRF_ISDIT_LAB',
    channel: 3,
    frequency: 2422,
    signal_level: -62.5,
    quality: 75,
    security: 'WPA2-Personal',
    security_flags: 'CCMP ',
    mode: 'Unknown'
  },
  {
    mac: '10:27:f5:69:36:ee',
    bssid: '10:27:f5:69:36:ee',
    ssid: 'ITDev-FM',
    channel: 3,
    frequency: 2422,
    signal_level: -50,
    quality: 100,
    security: 'WPA2-Personal',
    security_flags: 'CCMP ',
    mode: 'Unknown'
  },
  {
    mac: '54:13:79:1a:b2:ac',
    bssid: '54:13:79:1a:b2:ac',
    ssid: 'HP-Print-AC-LaserJet M12',
    channel: 6,
    frequency: 2437,
    signal_level: -69.5,
    quality: 61,
    security: 'Open',
    security_flags: 'None ',
    mode: 'Unknown'
  }
]
```

that is what I want.

But when I depoly this app on AWS cloud whose server is in America it is giving

**undefined**

Please solve my problem, either in any language.

I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: The client will not send this information to a server on the web, why should it?

Comment: Client have to send this information, to google API because of the Wi-Fi trilateration process